# Looking for non-paid heat map tools for website analytics

Tags: analytics

I'm looking for a heat map solution to track my users' behavior on my website, preferably free of charge. I've already googled a little bit and [here is what I found so far](http://www.dailybloggr.com/2010/03/4-free-heatmap-tools-for-tracking-user-behaviour-on-a-site/).

Still I would like to ask for some first hand experience, that'll help me make a better pick. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I know of:

- [Corunet Definitive Heatmap](http://blog.corunet.com/the-definitive-heatmap/)
- [Sec6](http://www.sec6.net/)
- [Mouseflow](http://mouseflow.com/)
- [Seevolution](http://www.seevolution.com/)

But there are also heatmap generators you can use for manual usertesting.

Answer (score 1):

Not quiet a heat map tool but Google analytics has - In-page Analytics section under Content. This shows the percentage of clicks in particular areas on the site and you can drill down through the pages. It also gives you all the usual stuff about time on site, bounce rate etc.